# Classic ASP Archive Function Only Archiving Fist File

Tags: post, checkbox, asp-classic, zip

#### Issue

I have an ASP function which is supposed to archive files based on which the user checks. For some reason, it is only archiving the first file.

For example, if the user checks the file `BD_Test1.txt` and `Test2.txt` the compressed file will only contain `BD_Test1.txt`.

#### HTML Code

```
<form method="post">
    Resume 1 <input type="checkbox" name=check1 value="BD_Test1.txt"><br>
    Resume 2 <input type="checkbox" name=check1 value="BD_Test2.txt"><br>
    Resume 3 <input type="checkbox" name=check1 value="BD_Test3.txt"><br>
    Resume 4 <input type="checkbox" name=check1 value="BD_Test4.txt"><br>
    Resume 5 <input type="checkbox" name=check1 value="BD_Test5.txt"><br>
    Resume 6 <input type="checkbox" name=check1 value="BD_Test6.txt"><br>
    Resume 7 <input type="checkbox" name=check1 value="BD_Test7.txt"><br>
    Resume 8 <input type="checkbox" name=check1 value="BD_Test8.txt"><br>
    Resume 9 <input type="checkbox" name=check1 value="BD_Test9.txt"><br>
    Resume 10 <input type="checkbox" name=check1 value="BD_Test10.txt"><br>
    <br><input type = "submit" name="zipFile" value = "Download"/><br>
</form>

<br><br>

<%
If (Request.Form("zipFile") <> "") Then
    Call archiveFile()
End If
%>
```

#### ASP Code

```
Function archiveFile()
    Dim request_Value, request_File
    Dim compress_Zip
    Dim i

    request_Value = Request("check1")
    request_File = split(request_Value,",")

    Set compress_Zip = Server.CreateObject("XStandard.Zip")

    For i = LBound(request_File) to UBound(request_File)
        compress_Zip.pack Server.MapPath("resumes/" & request_File(i)), Server.MapPath("compressed/BD_Compressed.zip")
    Next

    Set compress_Zip = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found found the issue, for anyone who would have the same issue...

The ASP code `request_File = split(request_Value,",")` is only splitting for a comma, not a command and space. Therefor, `request_File` was outputting `Test1.txt Test2.txt` where it should have been `Test1.txtTest2.txt`

This was telling the code to compress files that didn't exist.